# Taylor series for $f(x) = cos (x)$

Tags: taylor-expansion

For the function $f(x) = cos(x)$ I want a taylor series approximation accurate to within 0.1 of the actual function on an interval $-5\le x \le 5$. How would I determine the number of terms necessary to do this?

Comment: Look up remainder of alternating series on google

Comment: @qbert I was under the impression that cos (x) was not an alternating series, despite having positive and negative values, because it does not alternate between them?

Comment: @JQQ It's Taylor power-series expansion is an alternating series. (Of course only on the even indices. On the odd it is 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lauren remainder in Lagrange form is $$R_n(x) = \frac {f^{(n+1)}(c)} {(n+1)!}x^{n+1}$$ for some point $c$. 
So seeking for an $n$ for which $|R_n(x)| \lt 0.1$ means:

$|\frac {{cos}^{(n+1)}(c)} {(n+1)!} x^{n+1}| \le | \frac {x^{n+1}} {(n+1)!}| \lt \frac {5^{n+1}} {(n+1)!} \lt 0.1$ first for $n=13$ (check that), so $n=13$ is guaranteed to work.